# Auto delete pic/vids from phone when deleted from Google Photos web

Tags: sync, photos, google-photos

You take 10 photos and only one is good. But in Google Photos, all 10 are automatically uploaded. I don't want to maintain two places: my phone and the Google Photos Cloud.

How can I make it so that I only check Google Photos and the pictures or videos that I delete there are also automatically deleted from my smartphone (and without prompting)?

Comment: You can use folder sync app which let's you do bidirectional sync or in one direction. But, I don't know how to make folder sync see the folder where your photos are saved. You can create a separate folder where your photos are saved on any cloud including Drive // big caveat - uploading photos won't be as fast as it is with a Google photos. If you can live with that folder sync is a great option//Google system is not a true sync and creates problems like you face//You can use folder sync with any other cloud storage you own too

Comment: Based on quick testing, you have to also delete them from the Trash so that the files will be deleted physically, but this is after the Google Photos app is opened to sync the update from the cloud. However, I'm not sure if there's an option to disable the prompt or not.